# Trirand.Web.Mvc :: Filtered Grid State Data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

For a while i use the `jqGrid` component together with MVC, the *Trirand.Web.Mvc.dll*

First I will describe is what i’d like to achieve:

I have lots of orderlines in the grid, all goes well and smooth, let say 1000 orderlines.
A user click on a filter in the filtertoolbar, lets say filter all orderlines belong to an ordernr.

There are 225 orderlines belong to that order, and they're shown in the grid.

I click on “edit” (implemented with Action and Icon) I edit a field: orderlocation, and change to e.g. “Amsterdam”
After savebutton pressed in the grid, i have to ask : “Apply change on all filtered items?”

Let say, that’s a yes.

Then in the server side code, I've got a function “EditRow”

Now in this function, i do not only want the single orderline updated, but ALL filtered 225 orderlines -> all serverside.

How do I get this underlaying dataset?

```
public void EditRows(OrderLine orderline)
{
   …
   foreach (var filteredline in filteredorderlines) {
   }
}
```

How do i get filteredorderlines? 
GridSet State?

In ExportToExcel functions, they are using the same technique  (the filtered set is exported), but I couldn't figure out to reapply the filter in EditRow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just to inform anyone, I've found the solution here:

http://www.trirand.net/aspnetmvc/grid/exportpdf

GetExportData, gives datatable, based on the active filter

"je gaat het pas zien als je het doorhebt"

Comment: Please mark your question as answered if this solved your issue.